# Get all relations for a Model : mixing hasMany and belongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

It's about "libraries" and "users", but it can be seen as a more generic case.

- I have a `Library` model associated with a `libraries` table.
- The `libraries` table has a `creator_id` which is a reference to the `users` table.
- There is also a pivot table `library_user` for all the users who can **see** a library.

So I can get all the libraries associated to users via the pivot table by creating a method in `User` model like this:

```
public function librariesAssociatedViaPivot()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Library::class);
}
```

I can also create a function to get the libraries created by a `User`:

```
public function librariesCreatedByUser()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Library::class);
}
```

But What I want is the libraries the `User` **has created** + the libraries the `User` **can see**. In other words, I want to mix the two functions and be able to see all libraries for a `User` by calling:

```
$users->libraries
```

What should I put in this library method?

```
public function libraries()
{
    // ... ?
}
```

*Side note: I don't want to add the creator in the pivot table.*

Answer (score 0):

So `$user->librariesAssociatedViaPivot` and `$user->librariesCreatedByUser` both return a `Collection` of `Library`s? And you want to combine both?
In that case, simply do this:

```
public function libraries()
{
    return $this->librariesAssociatedViaPivot->merge($this->librariesCreatedByUser);
}
```

and use `$user->libraries()`.

Comment: Ok thanks. Still, I can't use `$users->libraries` and can't use fluent API of query builder (something like `$users->libraries()->orderBy('id')`)

Comment: If you want to use it as `$user->libraries`, you can name the function `getLibrariesAttribute()`. See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor).
You can use all the `Collection` methods, see [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#available-methods).

Comment: That's because it's returning a Collection. Use the collection methods instead like [`sortBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#available-methods).

Comment: You could also look into using [Unions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#unions)